# Porting iOS CATransform3D perspective (field m34) to Android using android.graphics.Camera

Tags: android, ios, 3d

**iOS Code:**

I have working code on iOS which prepares a 3D transformation for a UIView's layer:

```
CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
t.m34 = -1.0f/500.0f;
t = CATransform3DTranslate(t, 10.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f);
t = CATransform3DRotate(t, 0.25f * M_PI, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

I'm trying to port the above code to Android. I'm trying to prepare an `android.view.animation.Transformation t` which will do the same thing. It will be executed by `ViewGroup.getChildStaticTransformation(View v, Transformation t)`.

**unfinished Android Code:**

```
t.clear();
t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);
android.graphics.Camera camera = new android.graphics.Camera();
// set perspective (m34) here.. how??
camera.translate(10.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f);
camera.rotateX(-1.0f * Math.toDegrees(0.25 * Math.PI));
camera.getMatrix(t.getMatrix());
```

**My main issue:**

The main problem is that I'm not sure how set the perspective `t.m34 = -1.0f/500.0f` in Android. Reading the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) is rather cryptic and my best bet is using `Camera.setLocation()`. Also, the docs say nothing about units, so what would be an appropriate value?

Another issue is that `setLocation()` is only available from API 12, so I would really need to set it manually in the Matrix instead (or via some transformation). Any ideas how?

**Final comment:**

I'm aware that there are probably more issues.. like the `translate()` units, transformation order and generally the issue that we transform the camera in Android but the object in iOS. I will get to all of these later :)